# XCode 6 Tests Folder

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, swift, xcode6

XCode creates a tests folder when creating a new project. For example for a project called "MyProject" it creates also "MyProjectTests".

On some projects, I've deleted this folder completely (from XCode & Finder). This has been working fine on preview XCode.

On XCode 6 Beta 5, the same project that worked on Beta 4 now cannot compile:

```
error: could not read data from '/Users/some-path/MyProject/MyProjectTests/Info.plist': The file “Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
```

Did something change in beta 5? Are the tests folders required? What can I do?

PS. It's a Swift project - if it matters.

Comment: Update - Swift does not matter, I've opened an old ObjC project which worked on Beta 4, broken on beta 5 with the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the tests target from the project, too.

In the Project Navigator, select the project itself, then in the sidebar of the main window you'll see a <ProjectName>Tests item. Delete that and it should stop trying to build the tests you've deleted, which is what's causing your problem.